# Can not suspend my laptop Asus

Tags: 14.04, suspend, asus

I can't suspend my Asus laptop: after suspending it resumes again. So I can't suspend it at all. The problem started today.
Here you have some kernel logs. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

```
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.038769] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: remove, state 4
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.038795] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.039370] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.039388] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: remove, state 4
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.039403] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.050748] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.125781] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.516460] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Nov 21 21:26:38 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.734022] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.836392] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.838039] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.839169] PM: Entering mem sleep
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.839250] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.839435] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.839884] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856647] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856650] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856654] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856655] nouveau  [     DRM] waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856689] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1815.856996] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending kernel object tree...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.859432] nouveau E[   PDISP][0000:01:00.0][0xc000907c][ffff88023f670000] fini: 0xc2061088
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.859434] nouveau E[   PDISP][0000:01:00.0][0xc000907c][ffff88023f670000] failed suspend, -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.859435] nouveau E[     DRM] 0xd1500000:0xd15c7c00 suspend failed with -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.859452] nouveau E[     DRM] 0xdddddddd:0xd1500000 suspend failed with -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.859547] nouveau E[     DRM] 0xffffffff:0xdddddddd suspend failed with -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.860300] nouveau E[     DRM] 0xffffffff:0xffffffff suspend failed with -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.860412] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming display...
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.860431] nouveau E[     DRM] bo ffff8800368c4800 pinned elsewhere: 0x00000002 vs 0x00000004
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.860433] [drm:drm_helper_resume_force_mode] *ERROR* failed to set mode on crtc ffff88009c3ed000
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.862038] pci_pm_suspend(): nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x0/0xb0 [nouveau] returns -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.862041] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.862043] PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -16
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.862090] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.862190] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.878270] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.894453] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.894454] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1817.894454] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.222519] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.222554] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.223956] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.224121] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.224126] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.227360] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.227526] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.227531] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.227632] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.227633] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.228987] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.229412] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.236278] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.236284] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.240229] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1818.995285] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.666619] PM: resume of devices complete after 1802.638 msecs
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.675469] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.675470] Restarting tasks ... done.
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.676403] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.676679] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.841137] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.990891] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1819.990900] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001752] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001784] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001804] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001821] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001838] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001863] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 52 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001884] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.001897] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 57 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002286] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002296] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002304] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002312] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-39-generic xhci_hcd
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002319] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:04:00.0
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002775] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Nov 21 21:26:42 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.002810] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.016465] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.016492] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017188] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017198] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017205] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017210] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-39-generic xhci_hcd
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017215] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:04:00.0
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017702] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.017802] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.128436] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.135746] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.170311] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.174100] atl1c 0000:05:00.0: irq 59 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.189312] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.633797] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:35:3b:96:a0:b1
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.644002] wlan0: send auth to 5c:35:3b:96:a0:b1 (try 1/3)
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.646302] wlan0: authenticated
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.649020] wlan0: associate with 5c:35:3b:96:a0:b1 (try 1/3)
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.655800] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:35:3b:96:a0:b1 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.663329] wlan0: associated
Nov 21 21:26:43 jozix12-K53SD kernel: [ 1820.663391] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Suspend is infamously buggy on Ubuntu (edit: laptops). Sorry I can't give you a better explanation because I don't know the technical facts.

Comment: Look at the contents of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` --- it could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess but... worked for me. My new desktop failed to suspend because it has a XHC keyboard that woke it up immediatly. Running this script (I have it in `/etc/rc.local`) fixed it --- the only collateral effect is that I have to push the power button to resume, does not work from the keyboard.

```
#
# disabling wakeup on USB --- use just PWRB
#
for device in XHC EHC1 EHC2; do
    grep $device /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled > /dev/null && {
        echo Disabling wakeup on $device 
        echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    }
done
```